# Creating a Sub column in html

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I am learner and trying to make this table.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBsd2.jpg
Well, I have no idea how to add that image column within the column of table.
Can't find a solution anywhere.
Could anyone provide a solution for this.I would really be thankful.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the `rowspan` table attribute for the image to pass vertically through the table rows.

You'll also need to use `colspan` to continue the table cells horizontally below the image to flow to the end of the table.

google it for more info on how to use it...

```css
table {table-layout:fixed;}
```

```html
<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
 <tr>
  <td>Today's your lucky day. Look around, kiddo - it's all yours.</td>
  <td>Today's your lucky day. Look around, kiddo - it's all yours.</td>
  <td rowspan="5"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-200-200-8.jpg"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Today's your lucky day. Look around, kiddo - it's all yours.</td>
  <td>Today's your lucky day. Look around, kiddo - it's all yours.</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Today's your lucky day. Look around, kiddo - it's all yours.</td>
  <td>Today's your lucky day. Look around, kiddo - it's all yours.</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Today's your lucky day. Look around, kiddo - it's all yours.</td>
  <td>Today's your lucky day. Look around, kiddo - it's all yours.</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Today's your lucky day. Look around, kiddo - it's all yours.</td>
  <td>Today's your lucky day. Look around, kiddo - it's all yours.</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Today's your lucky day. Look around, kiddo - it's all yours.</td>
  <td colspan="2">Today's your lucky day. Look around, kiddo - it's all yours.</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Today's your lucky day. Look around, kiddo - it's all yours.</td>
  <td colspan="2">Today's your lucky day. Look around, kiddo - it's all yours.</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```